# Convert string to date time in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple question, but have been hiting my head against the wall on it . I have a date in a form of a string : `"03/30/2021 4:30 PM"` and i am looking to convert it into a datetime object.
I tried several approach but got errors in all of them:

```
2.6.3 :003 > Time.parse(@date).strftime("%b/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):3
        1: from (irb):3:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ArgumentError (argument out of range)

2.6.3 :004 > @date.to_datetime
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):4
        1: from (irb):4:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ArgumentError (invalid date)
```

I am sure this must not be complex, is there a one liner for this please ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DateTime.strptime("03/30/2021 4:30 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p") # =>  Tue, 30 Mar 2021 16:30:00 +0000
```

And here is the `strptime` method, https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, simple! i used: DateTime.strptime("03/30/2021 4:30 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %P").to_formatted_s(:db), but it also displays seconds, which I am trying to remove now:  "2021-03-30 16:30:00"